# Google App Engine appcfg.py raising Value Error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am following the app-engine mobile backend tutorial on the following website:
https://cloud.google.com/resources/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

I am developing on a Windows 8 machine and using Java 7 64-bit

I have installed app-engine-sdk-1.8.6 as an eclipse plugin and set the GAE_SDK_ROOT environment variable to:
E:\android-sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6

What I found surprising was there were no python files in the above installation directory.I had to manually download appcfg.py.

The tutorial uses an upload_data.sh file to Upload data to datastore.As I am developing on Windows I am using an equivalent batch file upload_data.bat whose contents are as follows:

python appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url="http://localhost:8888/remote_api" --filename $1 --kind=$2 -e nobody@nowhere.com

When I run the batch file I get the following error:

E:\AppEngineExample\UploadScript>upload_data.bat places.csv Place

```
E:\AppEngineExample\UploadScript>python appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml
 --url="http://localhost:8888/remote_api" --filename $1 --kind=$2 -e nobody@nowhere.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "appcfg.py", line 90, in <module>
    DIR_PATH = get_dir_path(os.path.join('lib', 'ipaddr'))
  File "appcfg.py", line 70, in get_dir_path
    'directory' % gae_sdk_root)
ValueError: GAE_SDK_ROOT 'E:\\android-sdk\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\\eclipse\\plugins\\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6\\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6' does not refer to a valid SDK directory
```

Please Help!!

Comment: This is simple work around. [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25332900/3144836)

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the same tutorial in a similar environment (Windows 8.1, Java 7 64 bit).

After a lot of struggling on the exact same issue *no upload_data argument available in the appcfg.cmd script in the bundled app engine SDK*, I decided to install Python 2.7 and the stand-alone app engine SDK (download it here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads).

In this stand-alone install there is the appcfg.py file (located in the root of the install folder, I've added this to the path). After this I created the following windows bat file to get the upload running successfully:

```
@echo off
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename=%1 --kind=%2 --email=nobody@nowhere.com
```

Run this script in the MobileAssistant-Data directory using this command:

```
upload_data.bat places.csv Place
```

I'm now continuing the tutorial, let's see what more obstacles are ahead ;)

Comment: I did exactly like you said and am getting the following error any idea? google.appengine.tools.bulkloader.FileNotFoundError
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10602991_10152630505917177_1101055729_n.jpg?oh=78a5f135e0bb8d26f3e6532b70a110d9&oe=53EC97D3&__gda__=1408009538_5334a45fcecea818c38f20daa18acd0a

Answer (score 0):

GAE has multiple SDK/runtimes, amongst them python and java.
appcfg.py it the tool for the python runtime.

The eclipse plugin SDK downloads the java SDK/runtime.  You use appcfg.cmd instead of appcfg.py

Running appcfg.py against the Java SDK will not work.

Comment: You are right!But how do I use the appcfg.cmd to upload data from an excel sheet to the datastore as it is shown in the above tutorial.Appcfg.cmd does not take an upload_data as an argument.